# decrypt and encrypt text with command line arguments

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault

I am trying to make a program that will encrypt and decrypt when user enters the string they want to encrypt/decrypt for `argv[2]` and enters either "encrypt" or "decrypt" for `argv[3]`. Here is the code I am trying to compile and run as of now

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    // char *string;
    char *key_ch;
    char  key_int;
    char *string_ = calloc(80, 1);
    string = argv[1];
    char encrypted_string[strlen(string)];
    char decrypted_string[strlen(string)];
    //char *key_ch;
    //char key_int;
    string = argv[1];
    key_ch = argv[2];
    key_int = atoi(key_ch);

    if (argc < 3)
    {
       printf("Not enough arguments!\n");
       exit (1);
    }

    if (strcmp(argv[3], "encrypt") == 0)
    {
            i = 0;
            while(i <= strlen(string)-1)
            {
                    encrypted_string[i] = string[i] + key_int;
                    i++;
            }

    //      printf("Encrypted string: ");
            i = 0;
            while (i <= strlen(string) -1)
            {
                    printf("%c", encrypted_string[i]);
                    i++;
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[3], "decrypt") == 0)
    {
            i = 0;
            while(i <= strlen(string) -1)
            {
                    decrypted_string[i] = string[i] - key_int;
                    i++;
            }

    //      printf("Decrypted String: ");
            i = 0;
            while (i <= strlen(string) -1)
            {
                    printf("%c", decrypted_string[i]);
                    i++;
            }

            printf("\n");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it without the `-Wall` command it compiles fine but when I run the program I am getting a segmentation fault, when I compile with `-Wall` I am getting

> sam0.c:9:24: warning: 'string' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
>
> char encrypted_string[strlen(string)];

**Can anyone possible shine some light on this error?** Thank you

**Edit:**
Changed my code to your suggestions. I am not getting a compiling error at all even when using "-Wall" however somewhere in my program it is causing me to get a segmentation fault... any ideas? I put quotes around where I changed my code for reference in case I did it wrong.

Comment: The problem is in your latest edit, you created two variations of the string variable:  `char *string_`, then you use `string` everywhere else.  Make them both the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a meaningful value for the variable can be determined, try to declare and initialize the variable in one step:

```
char *string = argv[1];
char encrypted_string[strlen(string)];
char decrypted_string[strlen(string)];
char *key_ch = argv[2];
char key_int = atoi(key_ch);
```

This will fix the warning: you were trying to get the length of an uninitialized string.

(here assuming C99. `char encrypted_string[strlen(string)]` is a [VLA](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). If you're restricted to C89 only [Rykker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36179769/3235496) works).

Also:

- use `const` to prevent unwanted modifications, e.g.

  ```
  const char *string = argv[1];
  /* ... */
  const char *key_ch = argv[2]
  ```
- `string` is a constant so you can get its length just one time (do not recalculate the length every time... take a look at [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)). So

  ```
  const char *string = argv[1];
  const int length = strlen(string);

  char encrypted_string[length];
  char decrypted_string[length];

  const char *key_ch = argv[2];
  char key_int = atoi(key_ch);
  ```
- check inputs: what happen if

  - `argc < 4`
  - `argv[3]` isn't in ("encrypt", "decrypt")
  - `key_ch` is not a number
  - `key_int` is too big
- you're printing `encrypted_string` / `decryped_string` one character at a time... and it works, but consider that if you want to manipulate them as 'strings' they aren't null terminated and their length isn't correct.
- *don't repeat yourself*. The differences between the encryption and the decryption phases are minimal: you can use just one buffer and change `key_int` to a negative value to decrypt.

Answer (score 1):

> warning: 'string' is used uninitialized in this function
>   [-Wuninitialized]

`char *string;` creates a pointer to char.  At this point it is not yet a string, but you are using it as a string argument.

Before using `char *string;` it must have memory assigned, and should be initialized.  Among other methoods, this *can* be done by:

```
char *string = calloc(80, 1);//initializes with known values (NULL).
```

Now `string` is usable, but has zero length.  Values can be assigned via string functions:

```
strcpy(string, argv[1]);
sprintf(string, "%s", argv[1]);
strcat(string, argv[1]);
```

... *[more string functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/)*

When using input from command line, `argv, argc`, `malloc/calloc` and string cpy functions can be avoided by using `strdup`.  a value can be assigned like this:

```
if(argc == 2)
{
    char *string = strdup(argv[1]);
    if(!string) return -1;
    ...
```

*EDIT*  (addressing your OP edit)
You are now using two different variables:  `string_` and `string`

```
char *string_ = calloc(80, 1);
            ^
string = argv[1];
```

Make them the same throughout your code and it should build and run.

Comment: Merging two answers isn't always the best option :-). +1

Answer (score 0):

```
char *string;
char encrypted_string[strlen(string)];
char decrypted_string[strlen(string)];
```

This results in undefined behavior - you try to get the length of an uninitialized piece of memory (I'm amazed that your program doesn't crash). You may only call `strlen` after assigning something to `string`.

The easiest fix (assuming you don't want to start using `malloc`, `strdup`, etc.) would be moving the last two lines after `string = argv[1];`

Also, you need to check `argc` to make sure enough arguments have been passed!